# scheme loop does not iterate through all elements in the list

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, scheme, racket, let

I am trying to change the elements on a list based on a criteria. Let's say I have a list,
L = '(0 1 1 0 0). I want only the first "zero" found in this list as "zero", and for any other "zero" in that list, I want them to be 1. So the list of my example will become L = '(0 1 1 1 1). This is what I have done so far,

```
(let dLoop ((L '(0 1 1 0 0))
            (i 0)
            (j 1))
  (if (and (<= i (length L)) (<= j (- (length L) 1)))
      (begin
        (if (zero? (list-ref L i))
            (begin
              (cond
                [(zero? (list-ref L j)) (list-set L j 1)]
                [else (dLoop L i (add1 j))]
                )
              )
            (dLoop L (add1 i) (add1 j))))
      L))
```

This only returns, L = '(0 1 1 1 0)

For some reason, the moment it finds the first duplicate zero, the code terminates! I would really appreciate some insights regarding this issue

Comment: Perhaps instead of iterating over the loop like one would in C, you could use `cdr` and `cons`; an approach more typically seen in lisps.

Answer (score 1):

In your (cond) expression, you don't have a recursive call to dLoop if (zero? (list-ref L j)) case evaluates. This causes the (cond) to return, then the (begin) returns and finally exits out of you (let) expression. Adding on to what Lazer said however, this is kinda not the standard scheme approach, let alone very efficient since (list-ref) on linked-lists is O(n) each time. Perhaps try something like:

```lisp
(define (find-and-map-rest lst pred f)
  (cond [(null? lst) lst]
        ;; found the thing
        [(pred (car lst)) (cons (car lst)
                                (map f (cdr lst)))]
        ;; didn't find the thing... yet
        [else (cons (car lst)
                    (find-and-map-rest (cdr lst)
                                       pred f))]))


(define (zero->one x)
   (if (zero? x) 1 x))

(find-and-map-rest '(0 1 1 0 0) zero? zero->one)
```

Answer (score 0):

Realistic code is probably not going to do all of that `cons`ing for a task like this. All that the code really needs to do is find the first zero, take the first part of the list up to and including that zero, and append it to a list of ones as long as the rest of the input list. If no zero is found, the result is just the input list:

```
(define (f xs)
  (let ((rest (member 0 xs)))
    (if rest
        (let ((ones-count (sub1 (length rest))))
          (append (take xs (- (length xs) ones-count))
                  (make-list ones-count 1)))
        xs)))
```

Sample interaction:

```
scratch.rkt> (f '(0))
'(0)
scratch.rkt> (f '(1))
'(1)
scratch.rkt> (f '(0 1 1 0 0))
'(0 1 1 1 1)
scratch.rkt> (f '(1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0))
'(1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1)
```